# Can .bash_profile automatically run without sourcing it in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, vim, osx-mavericks, iterm2, .bash-profile

I am using iTerm2 in Mavericks OSX and made sure I updated to the latest version. My working directory inside preferences is set to Home Directory.

I was watching a tutorial on iTerm customization and this author I was listening to managed to have this scripts run automatically every time he just saves (":wq") out of Vim editor.

I am new to the Mac so I literally wasted a few hours trying to figure why my iTerm wasn't updating its color. It turns out I have to type "source .bash_profile" also.

From the video, the author taught how to download and install iTerm, typed "sudo vim .bash_profile" and pasted a script. I am sure there were not changes to the preferences other than the default. Did I miss something?

Thank you

Comment: After updating `.bash_profile`, did you open a new tab or new window of your terminal? Otherwise you have to source `.bash_profile`. Btw, using `sudo` for `vim .bash_profile` is really weird, so I would question everything else the author says.

Comment: Link to video, please?

Comment: Like Janos said, using `sudo` to edit `.bash_profile` is odd, since `.bash_profile` is meant to be owned by the user (you), and `su`/`sudo` are used to do stuff as a different user. Sounds tacky, indeed. And on that matter, the only stuff you really need to do inside `.bash_profile` while using `iTerm2` is stuff like path variables, PS1, sourcing and stuff. Changing stuff like, you said, background color would be easiest to do via `iTerm2`'s own preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to get the changes in your profile to be applied is to restart your terminal. This is because it is a script set to run at login. `bash .bash_profile` or `exec ~/.bash_profile` will not work as these commands will open a new bash process.